# elasticsearch - is it possible to set indices.ttl.interval dynamically

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

is it possible to set to index - indices.ttl.interval dynamically ?

i tried , and get this exception : Can't update non dynamic settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
Didn't find correct documentation for the correct syntax, so with fews try i succeeded  :
PUT to : localhost:9200/_cluster/settings
body: 
{
    "persistent" : {
        "indices.ttl.interval" : "120"
    }
}

it will survive the restart.

or

{
    "transient" : {
        "indices.ttl.interval" : "120"
    }
}

it will take effect until you restart the service
```

Comment: Do you have to restart cluster to make the setting effective?